# Equivalence between Ising model and lattice gas model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

The Ising Hamiltonian is

$$
H=-J \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i \sigma_{i+1} - H \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i
$$
How I can show the lattice gas model Hamiltonian is equivalent to that of the Ising model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Lattice gas hamiltonian is:

$$H = A\sum_{i=1}^N  n_i + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j} B_{ij}n_in_j $$

If we want to map this into Ising we just need to take a lattice such that the occupation number can only be $n_i=0,1$ (which is always possible) and then substitute:

$$n_i = \frac{1}{2} (1+S_i)$$

$S_i$ can assume values $-1$ or $+1$. The first term of the hamiltonian simply becomes:

$$\frac{A}{2}N + \frac{A}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N S_i$$

the second one instead is:

$$\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i,j} B_{ij} + \frac{1}{8}\sum_{i,j} B_{ij} (S_i+S_j) + \frac{1}{8}\sum_{i,j} B_{ij}S_iS_j $$

Assuming $B_{ij}=B_{ji}$ you can write $\sum_{i,j} B_{ij} (S_i+S_j) = 2\sum_{i,j} B_{ij}S_i$ by simply swapping the indices' names in the sum. Finally, assuming $B_{ij} = B$ for nearest neighbours and $0$ otherwise, the interacting term becomes:

$$\frac{BzN}{8} + \frac{Bz}{4}\sum_{i} S_i + \frac{B}{8}\sum_{\left\langle i,j \right\rangle} S_iS_j $$

(Here $z$ is the number of nearest neighbours). Putting everything together you get:

$$ H = \left( \frac{AN}{2}+\frac{BzN}{8} \right) + \left( \frac{A}{2}+\frac{Bz}{4} \right) \sum_{i} S_i + \frac{B}{8}\sum_{\left\langle i,j \right\rangle} S_iS_j $$

Now you set $h=-\left( \frac{A}{2}+\frac{Bz}{4} \right)$; $J=-B/8$ and you have Ising hamiltonian rescaled by a constant, which is not important for any thermodynamical property.

Comment: Hmm I found this -BH = V sum ni*nj +u sum ni What is this

Comment: The derivation I made is a bit more general: I just get to the nearest neighbours interaction at the end (I followed the calculation on my Statistical Mechanics notes).

Comment: Ok Thanks But how are n1 v and u related to si, j and H ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand your question... 
I think that mapping lattice gas into Ising is only a formal mapping: Lattice gas and Ising are models that describe totally different sistems, but there's a formal mapping between them, which means that they have similar thermodynamical properties.

Comment: Ok no problem and if you like my questions please give vote