# Mean field theory for Ising model with 0,1

Tags: ising-model, mean-field-theory

I'm trying to derive a mean field expression of the dependence of the mean field of a 1D Ising ring model with $\sigma_i=0,1$.

What I have derived so far is:

The Hamiltonian

$$H=-J\sum_i\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}$$

The partition function

$$ Z=\Pi_i\sum_{\sigma_i=0,1} \exp\left(-\frac{J}{k_bT}\sum_i\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}\right)$$

Taking account all the possible products:

$$\sum_{\sigma_i=0,1}\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}=1\times1+1\times0+0\times1+0\times0=1$$

Then we have
$$Z=\Pi_i\left(e^{N\frac{J}{k_bT}}+3\right)^N$$

This is here where I'm stuck.

I eventually want to add a weak magnetic field see how the system behaves as a function of $J$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not directly answer your question but give you extra informations (LPZ's nice answer is the one you want).
What you are looking at is the lattice gas model. You can imagine particles on a lattice hopping around. $\sigma_i=0$ represents the absence of particles and $\sigma_i = 1$ represents the existence of a particle at site $i$. The "magnetic field" is akin to a chemical potential and the $J$ is akin to an attractive potential (while the repulsive part of real potential is taken into account by the fact that you can only have one particle by lattice site, you could define more state than two if you want to go beyond that).

The nice thing is that, you can linearly map the ising model to the lattice gas model. Indeed, from your model:

$$H = -J\sum_{i}\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1} + h\sum_i\sigma_i$$

we can go to the ising model by using the following relation: $\sigma_i = \frac{1}{2} (1+s_i)$. You see that $s_i$ is $-1$ and $1$ when $\sigma_i$ is 0 and $1$. Performing this change of variable in your Hamiltonian will result in a new Hamiltonian with variable similar to an ising model (-1 and 1), but with interaction $J'\neq J$ and magnetic field $h'\neq h$ and an unimportant constant term. From this Hamiltonian, you can apply the usual mean field approach (or an exact one, in 1D) that you can find everywhere and thus solve your problem.

**Edit**: [Here is a PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/361402/232790) talking about exactly that

---

**Edit2**: More informations in 1D (the ND derivation is simple).
$$H = -J\sum_{i}\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1} + h\sum_i\sigma_i$$ is you initial Hamiltonian:
$$H = -\dfrac{J}{4}\sum_{i}(1 + s_i)(1 + s_{i+1}) + \dfrac{h}{2}\sum_i s_i= \dfrac{J}{4}\sum_{i}s_is_{i+1} + \left(\dfrac{h}{2} + J\right)\sum_{i}s_i + cst$$

Where the constant term includes things independent on $s_i$ but dependent on $N$ or $J$. These will not affect the thermodynamics of your model.

You see that you can simply solve the ising model with hamiltonian $H'$ for $J' = J/4$ and $h' = h/2 + J$. The critical temperature of your ising model with $H'$ will be the same as the critical temperature of your model with spin 0 and 1.

Your model will be critical when $h' = 0$ (critical ising model), that is $h/2 + J = 0§.
For an ising model this gives the following phase diagram:
[image]

To go to the lattice gas model, you simply need to to the usual change of variable $\langle \sigma \rangle = \dfrac{1}{2}(1 + \langle s_i\rangle) $ which simply brings your whole phase diagram upward (here $\rho = \langle \sigma\rangle$):
[image]
There are some difficulties on the interpretation of this phase diagram when we talk about a lattice gas model. It has not exactly the same interpretation than an ising one. I could talk about that if you wish.

---

On a side note, in your question, you were beginning to solve exactly your system and you were not using any mean field approach!

Comment: This is actually very helpful as I can directly use the known solution of the Ising model, and just make the transformation between the two systems. Perhaps you can elaborate on this a bit more? not write the entire derivation but mention what are the transformations, and how the bifurcation diagrams would appear with respect to the two systems. I'll accept the answer for that clarification.

Comment: I might do an update later today if I find the time

Comment: I very quickly updated thhe answer on top of my head. This is very very probable that somehyting is completely wrong. If you spot something weird or want more information. Please tell me, I'll update it later.

Comment: @jarhead note however that LPZ approach is more general and probably more interesting. But it is exact and thus not mean field. You won't obtain a phase transition in 1D with the exact solution.

Comment: Thanks, that is noted.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is wrong because the individual interactions are not independent. You cannot thus factorize your partition function. Also, I don't quite understand your notation, you are doing a product over $i$ and then a sum over $i$ for the energy. There is no product, you just sum over the $2^N$ possible $\sigma$.  The standard approach of exactly solving this kind of models is to use transfer matrices. You recognise your partition function as a trace of matrix exponentiation:
$$
Z = \text{Tr}(T^N) \\
T = \begin{pmatrix}
e^J & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(I absorbed $J\to \beta J$). You just need to diagonalise $T$ to get the exact formula. In the thermodynamic limit, the free energy density is given by the logarithm of the biggest eigenvalue. Adding a magnetic field just modifies the diagonal components of $T$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is the matrix made of three 0 or three 1s? Since you'd have $e^0=1$ for every states involving a sum over lattice variables equal to 0?

Comment: Yes you’re right, corrected